# How to add key value pair in solr dynamically?

Tags: solr

I have a scenario, where i have to add number of user clicks corresponding to a query on the clicked document in solr. I came accross use of dynamic fields but i am not sure how to use them for this purpose specifically. Here is what i want

Let's say user queries , "Effel Tower" and clicks on a link, a value having the query keyword should be added to solr against that document along with the number of clicks corresponding to that query for that particular document. Eventually i should be able to sort the solr results when the same query is executed based on the number of clicks.

I am not sure about feasibility of this. Please guide me with the best possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, that would work - but it will need a bit of code to make it work decently. Be careful about validating the query strings so that users can overwrite custom properties on your *other* fields in the document. Prefix the query string with `query_string_` or something similar and add a `dynamicField` definition that matches `query_string_*`.

You're going to need docValues to be set if you're going to sort by a large number of different field names, since the internal lucene cache will lead to a out of memory exception otherwise if you're sorting by many distinct fields (even if those fields have sparse values only present in a small number of documents, the cache will contain a reference to all the document ids).

However, having a separate collection for a clickstream dataset is probably easier to maintain and scale, where you insert a document for each click, with a reference to the document id being clicked, a date for the click and the query. That way you can facet on the query and apply a range for click dates if you want to see what's been popular the last x days, etc.

The final note: click data is usually not *that* relevant by itself. You want to augment this data with whether the user returned to the search result or not, and whether it was the last link the user clicked. You also want to compare the click frequency against the expected click frequency for the position in the search result - otherwise you're just going to bias your search results in the same way as they're already ordered. People click the first or second hit - that's what you're already telling them is the most relevant - so using the fact that they clicked that link as an input to how to rank documents won't give you any useful data.